# Create a yellow color slider for light bulb dimming effect

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am a newbie at front end web development and I have been given a task to create a slider that is linked to a bulb giving an effect of dimming and brightening according to how the slider is manipulated. Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: sorry man, but here we help when you have a specific programming issue, not when you ask for a tutorial. Try to do your job and come back here when you have some code to show, bye

Comment: I just needed direction, but noted.

Comment: I see, @dominicbure, you can find some rules [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: @dominicbure wait 5 minutes, I'll have an example for you

Comment: @Isaac thanks.ddb thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you'll have to do some fancy css to get an image of a lightbulb positioned behind the div with the colour in it, I've made a basic example which you can view here: https://jsfiddle.net/IsaacAdni/q56zkf2t/.

Essentially, you create two divs, styling the swatch with a width and height using css too (not shown below):

```
<div id="yellow"></div>
<div id="swatch"></div>
```

Then you make one of them a slider using jQuery:

```
$("#yellow").slider({
  orientation: "horizontal",
  range: "min",
  max: 255,
  value: 127,
  slide: refreshSwatch,
  change: refreshSwatch
});
```

And now the function refreshSwatch will be called every time the position of the slider is changed. We can use this function to change the opacity of the swatch:

```
function refreshSwatch() {
  var yellow = $("#yellow").slider("value");
  var alpha = yellow / 255;
  $("#swatch").css("background-color", "rgba(255, 255, 0, " + alpha + ");");
}
```

Making the swatch appear over an image of a lightbulb will be the hard part, but I'll leave that up to you.